# How to create Right-Click ActionMenu at mouse position?

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, eventhandler, dynamic

I have a `Grid` and need to enable some actions on individual values.  For this I want to use an `ActionMenu` that shows on *right-click* of the grid cell.

This should behave just as the normal right-click menu. 
On a selection being made the action would evaluate and the `ActionMenu` would disappear. 
On clicking anywhere off of the `ActionMenu` it would disappear.

I am stuck on the first part of showing the `ActionMenu`.  I know I need to use `CurrentValue["MousePosition"]` to position it but am not certain how to do this or how to get it to disappear.

A minimal `Grid` example is below.

```
Grid@MapIndexed[
  EventHandler[
    #1,
    {{"MouseClicked", 2} :> 
      ActionMenu["Action List", {"Value" :> Echo@#1, "Index" :> Echo@#2}]}
    ] &,
  Partition[Range[4], 2],
  {2}
  ]
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both solutions are undocumented but I don't think they will go away. `Menu/MenuItem` are used internally for a long time and `AttachedCell` is a relatively new concept but many of new features use it. E.g. `DateSetter[]`, suggestion toolbar, image tools, message stack preview, etc.

#### ContextMenu

Quite out of the box. One needs to remember to use `KernelExecute` for procedures which can not be performed by the FrontEnd. Also, `MenuEvaluator` must be set to `Automatic` or a specific name of the Kernel you want to use. Otherwise the FrontEnd will try to run the procedure and it will probably fail returning 'unknown packet dialog'. Why both are needed? I don't know.

```
Grid @ MapIndexed[
  Style[ #1, ContextMenu -> {
    MenuItem["Value", KernelExecute@Echo@#, MenuEvaluator -> Automatic], 
    MenuItem["Index", KernelExecute@Echo@#2, MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]
  }] &,
  Partition[Range[4], 2], {2}
]
```

[image]

#### Undocumented AttachedCell usage, more flexible

A small example:

```
menu = With[
     {ca := NotebookDelete@EvaluationCell[]}
  ,  MathLink`CallFrontEnd[ FrontEnd`AttachCell[
         EvaluationBox[]
       , Cell[ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ ButtonBar[
              {"Value" :> (ca; Echo@#1), "Index" :> (ca; Echo@#2)}
            , Appearance -> "Vertical"
         ]]
       , Center, Center, "ClosingActions" -> {"OutsideMouseClick"}
     ]]
] &


Grid @ MapIndexed[
  EventHandler[#1, {{"MouseClicked", 2} :> (menu[#, #2])}] &, 
  Partition[Range[4], 2], {2}]
```

[image]

For more examples with an `AttachedCell` search around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58145/discussion-between-edmund-and-kuba).

Comment: Not on this site often enough anymore. Only just read this. `Style[...,ContextMenu...]` is a good find. I've had to place a ContextMenu.tr file in the FrontEnd>TextResources path to customise the context menu but this is potentially a much better solution