# Context menu in CDF Player

Tags: front-end, gui-construction

Using `Style` with the option `ContextMenu` or `AttachedCell` it is possible to create context menus in Mathematica user interfaces. Both of these are undocumented, but shown in other answers on this site, see e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145139/169) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99292/169) and actually work well since several versions. But I recently detected that both do not work as expected when used in CDF Player or CDF Player Pro (I have tested this in version 10.4.1 and would actually need this to work in that version, but the problem persists with newer versions). The easiest way to test this is using the menu entry File -> CDF Preview.

The `ContextMenu` option seems to be ignored in CDF Player and the `Attached` cell is not closed when selecting an entry as it does in Mathematica (most probably because `NotebookDelete` does not work in the players).

Does anyone know if there is some "magic" option setting that will make either of them work in the Player versions or another workaround which would allow to define (right click) context menus so that they work in CDF Player and/or CDF Player Pro?

Here is some example code to show what it is that I am trying to get working:

Using the `ContextMenu` option (prefered):

```
 Style[
   Panel@Pane["Pane with context menu", {200, 200}],
   ContextMenu -> {
     MenuItem["One", KernelExecute@MessageDialog@"One",
       MenuEvaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Queued"],
     MenuItem["Two", KernelExecute@MessageDialog@"Two",
       MenuEvaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Queued"]
   }
 ]
```

or using attached cells:

```
EventHandler[
  Panel@Pane["Pane with context menu", {200, 200}],
  {
    {"MouseClicked", 2} :> MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
      FrontEnd`AttachCell[
        EvaluationBox[],
        Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Grid[{{
              Button["One", 
                NotebookDelete@EvaluationCell[];MessageDialog@"One",
                Appearance -> "Palette", Alignment -> Left
              ]
            }, {
              Button["Two", 
                NotebookDelete@EvaluationCell[] MessageDialog@"Two",
                Appearance -> "Palette", Alignment -> Left
              ]
            }},
            Spacings -> {0, 0}, BaseStyle -> "Panel"
        ]],
        {Automatic, {Center, Top}},
        {Left, Top},
        "ClosingActions" -> {"OutsideMouseClick", "EvaluatorQuit"}
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Albert why have you explicitly added the `System\`` context? e.g `System\``ContextMenu? If the explicit context is needed the reason it is not working is probably because the `System` context gets stripped off. I have encountered this before and had to edit the file in a text editor to add it back, e.g. for `System\`MenuConfiguration` This will work for a `*.nb` but may lead to problems with `*.cdf`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: it is there for no specific reason, I think I just copied that part from somewhere. I just tried the same code without the System context and it doesn't make a difference (works in Mathematica but does not work in Player). But as it is not necessary I have changed it in the example code...

Comment: I would recommend to avoid using CDF

Comment: @M.R.: unfortunately that is not an option (actually no CDF is involved, the code is encoded packages running in Player Pro) . There are 30+ users for this, using Mathematica instead of Player Pro for them would mean to pay for 30+ license upgrades (I would then rather not use a context menu at all)...

Comment: @AlbertRetey does PacletManager work in PlayerPro?

Comment: @Kuba: downloading and installing does work, we are using that on a regular basis...

Comment: @AlbertRetey great news :) thanks. p.s. nice score you have there :)

Comment: @Kuba: just realized that when you mentioned it. I think I'll strictly refuse any reputation changes from now on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a budget solution:

```
WithBudgetContextMenu[expr_, actions : {__RuleDelayed}] := 
 DynamicModule[{layers, activeLayer, hideMenu, showMenu, alignment},
  showMenu[] := (layers = {1, 2}; activeLayer = 2; 
    alignment = MousePosition["EventHandlerScaled"]);
  hideMenu[] := (layers = {1}; activeLayer = 1);
  hideMenu[]; 
  EventHandler[#, {"MouseClicked", 1} :> hideMenu[], 
       PassEventsDown -> True] &@
     EventHandler[#, {"MouseClicked", 2} :> showMenu[]] &@
   Overlay[{expr, 
     Grid[actions /. 
       RuleDelayed[lbl_, 
         action_] :> {Button[lbl, action;, Appearance -> "Palette", 
          Alignment -> Left, 
          ImageSize -> CurrentValue["DefaultButtonSize"]]}, 
      Spacings -> {0, 0}, BaseStyle -> "Panel"]}, Dynamic@layers, 
    Dynamic@activeLayer,
    Alignment -> Dynamic[2 (alignment - .5)]]]
```

Works even in a FreePlayer:

```
WithBudgetContextMenu[
  Panel @ Pane["Pane with context menu", {500, 500}]
, {"One" :> MessageDialog@"One", "Two" :> MessageDialog@"Two"}
] // CDFDeploy["test.cdf", #] &
```

[image]

Here is another variation with a more fine grained control:

```
WithBudgetContextMenu2[panel_, Dynamic@layerController_] := 
 DynamicModule[{layers = {1}, activeLayer = 1, actionsMenu},
  EventHandler[#, {"MouseClicked", 1} :> layerController["Hide"], 
     PassEventsDown -> True] &@
   Overlay[
    {panel,
     Dynamic@actionsMenu
     },
    Dynamic@layers,
    Dynamic@activeLayer,
    Alignment -> {Center, Center}
    ],
  Initialization :> (
    layerController["Show"] := Function[actions,
      actionsMenu = Grid[
        List /@ BudgetContextMenu2MenuItem /@ actions
        , Spacings -> {0, 0}, BaseStyle -> "Panel"];
      layers = {1, 2}; activeLayer = 2
      ];
    layerController["Hide"] := (layers = {1}; activeLayer = 1);
    )
  ]

BudgetContextMenu2MenuItem[lbl_ :> action_] := 
 Button[lbl, action, Appearance -> "Palette", Alignment -> Left, 
  ImageSize -> CurrentValue["DefaultButtonSize"]]

BudgetContextMenu2EventHandler[expr_, Dynamic@menuToggler_, 
  actions : {__RuleDelayed}] := 
 EventHandler[
  expr, {"MouseClicked", 2} :> (menuToggler["Show"]@actions)]

DynamicModule[{menu},
  WithBudgetContextMenu2[
   Panel[#, ImageSize -> {200, 200}] &@Column[{
      BudgetContextMenu2EventHandler[
       Framed["Pane with context menu"], 
       Dynamic@menu, {"One" :> MessageDialog@"One"}
       ],
      BudgetContextMenu2EventHandler[
       Framed["Another Pane with context menu"], 
       Dynamic@menu, {"Two" :> MessageDialog@"Two"}
       ]

      }],
   Dynamic@menu
   ],
  SaveDefinitions -> True
  ] // CDFDeploy["test.cdf", #] &
```